# React MUI - custom colors in Alert component - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, themes

I'm trying to theme and customize MUI components to align them with our company design, but I stumbled across a problem.

I have defined my custom colors, for some reason we have color "danger" instead of "error".
I was following the documentation https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/#adding-new-colors and everything works great for Button component.
But when I moved on to the Alert component, the same approach doesn't work, and I just simply don't know why. All I'm getting is ***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')***

I also tried it to add it to the stackblitz example from the docs page mentioned above but got the same result: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-z3xjhf?file=demo.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Alert from '@mui/material/Alert';

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    neutral: {
      main: '#64748B',
      contrastText: '#fff',
    },
  },
});

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface Palette {
    neutral: Palette['primary'];
  }

  // allow configuration using `createTheme`
  interface PaletteOptions {
    neutral?: PaletteOptions['primary'];
  }
}

// Update the Button's color prop options
declare module '@mui/material/Button' {
  interface ButtonPropsColorOverrides {
    neutral: true;
  }
}

declare module '@mui/material/Alert' {
  interface AlertPropsColorOverrides {
    neutral: true;
  }
}

export default function CustomColor() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Button color="neutral" variant="contained">
        neutral
      </Button>
      <Alert color="neutral">ALERT</Alert>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi! Can you please share your code so we can figure it out?

Comment: Live demo is in the stackblitz link I shared but I added the code also to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `light: '<whatever_your_light_color_hex>'` to your theme, too. Like this:

```js
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    neutral: {
      main: '#64748B',
      light: '#64748B',
      contrastText: '#fff',
    },
  },
});
```

[This stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-z3xjhf-cicdth?file=demo.tsx) is a live working example of this solution.